# Make svelte monitor change of a json object from express backend

Tags: node.js, express, svelte, real-time

I have an express app that uses ejs. On the backend I have a json object that can be around 100MB.

With my api call on the frontend, I fetch the json with jquery ajax requests and print the result in the page. Each entry of the json is a bootstrap container on my front.

The method I use is not fast enough. The browser crash if the JSON is big. It fetches the json quickly but the view lags a lot and crashes the firefox tab.

I want to use svelte and make it replace ejs and jquery. Apparently svelte is good for its performance. Thus it may solve my problem.

The thing is, I want when the json from the server changes (an element added or deleted) for the information to be automatically updated in my front.

In jquery I did that by fetching the json every 1 sec (ofc lagging increases). How can I make this effect with svelte ?

PS: I still did not pass to svelte but I want to change from jquery and use modern frameworks. So if you have any other non svelte suggestion I am open to it to.

Comment: How does the server handle changes for the json? If there is a function handling the changes, you can try using a simple websocket that lets the server side talk to the client side. _Note: fetching anything (especially something big) every 1 sec is just bad practice in any language_